# How can I commit an entry to a static variable?

Tags: apex, string, method, static

In one method I set the value of a static variable, in the other I want to get it, but I get null:

```
public class CurrencyExchangeController {
    
    public static String requestDate;

    @future(callout=true)
    public static void calloutCurrency() {
        ...
        System.debug(requestDate); //this is null
    }

    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<Exchange_Rate__c> getLastExchangeRates (){
        ...
        requestDate = 'test';
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's expected. Since future methods are in a separate transaction, whatever value was stored before won't exist, because static variables aren't preserved across transactions. You need to simply pass in the value as a parameter:

```
@future(callout=true)
public static void calloutCurrency(String requestDate) {
    ...
    System.debug(requestDate);
}

@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static List<Exchange_Rate__c> getLastExchangeRates (){
    ...
    calloutCurrency('test');
}
```

Comment: Thanks. And there are no workarounds? My method initially took a parameter, as you noted in your answer. However, I have two similar methods and I wanted to optimize this by combining it into one, without using the parameter that the method should take.

Comment: @uniqueuser The future method needs the parameter, full stop. A typical solution is to write two functions that call the same function, with differing paremeters: `static void callWithoutParam() { calloutCurrency(null); } callWithParam(String param) { calloutCurrency(param); }`

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I will do so.